# what is the difference between using elasticsearch shutdown api and killing the elasticsearch process?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know the difference between using elasticsearch shutdown api and killing the elasticsearch process (ctrl+c). I actually don't take graceful shut down as the answer coz I want to know what actually ES does when a shut down API call is issued.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences that I'm aware of (fair warning there may be more):

1. Provides a single endpoint for shutting one, some or all of the
   nodes in a cluster. A nice convenience when dealing with larger
   clusters.
2. Avoids the re-balance problem that can occur when shutting down
   nodes individually. An import scenario to avoid when using larger
   clusters. You start shutting down nodes one by one and you either
   get distracted or it takes too long. Now the surviving nodes think
   that there have been node failures and start re-balancing the
   cluster, which may then get interrupted by the remaining nodes
   shutdown. Can leave a real mess. Using the shutdown api specifically
   avoids this problem:
   http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Stopping-the-entire-cluster-without-any-rebalancing-td3431242.html

Other than that, after a cursory look thru the source code I don't see much difference.